# SORTED Angular 6 Communication Service between 2 components

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Hi guys i am strugglin with Angular 6 and its components, i created a service to communicate one event that is triggered in one component and when its happened reload other component.

The code is of the service is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CommunicationService {

private subject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

constructor() { }

public change(){
  this.subject.next(true);
}

public getChange(): Observable<boolean>{
  return this.subject.asObservable();
 }

}
```

then the Observable component code:

```
public subscription: Subscription;

constructor(
private _router: Router,
private _communication: CommunicationService
){}

loginUser()
{
  this._router.navigate(['./loginUser']);
  this.subscription= Observable.interval(500).subscribe(x=> 
  {
   this._communication.getChange().subscribe( resp=>{
    if(resp===true){
        this.ngOnInit();
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  })
});

  }
```

and the trigger component code:

```
this._communication.change();
```

Basically the las component import the Communication Service and call the method change() i was debbuging the code and the it seems do it all right but i allways get false in the response of the subscription, even when the method changed is called, what i am doing wrong?

UPDATE SORTED
My first code was right the problem was importing the service in both components in providers instead of importing it in app module. Ït's works fine

Comment: try subscribing into the ng_OnInit() function

Comment: i tried, not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the service

```
  private subject= new BehaviorSubject(false);
  curretSubject = this.subject.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  public changeSubject(fl: boolean) {
    this.subject.next(fl)
   }
```

component:

```
 loginUser()
  {
    this._router.navigate(['./loginUser']);
    this.subscription= Observable.interval(500).subscribe(x=> 
    {
     this._communication.curretSubject.subscribe( resp=>{
      if(resp===true){
          this.ngOnInit();
          this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    })
  });

  }
```

trigger:

```
this._communication.changeSubject(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, i tried that and i am still getting always false :(

Comment: @DanielRodriguez can you post the place you call changeSubject?

Comment: the code seems to be right.. are  v sure that it goes into the else of resp2

Comment: please put my answer

Comment: the thing is when i was debbuging i debbuged the changeSubject method it works fine and change the value of the BehaviorSubject but the observable object return false

Comment: obviously onsubmit() is called before of loginUser()

Comment: not it is called after, first loginUser() and then onsubmit()

Comment: So that's the problem you have to call before the changing method

Comment: i dont know how to do that i put subscribe listening every 0,5 secs so there is a point where the trigger calls onsubmit() and then changeSubject and after that the subscribe should take the new response,  if not ,how it works?

Comment: yes when changes  the subscribe take the new answer..I think

Comment: should but not :(

Answer (score 0):

after a few changes the code is like that:

service:

```
 private subject= new BehaviorSubject(false);
  currentSubject = this.subject.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  public change(fl: boolean) {
    this.subject.next(fl);
   }
```

component listening with invertal of 0,5:

```
 loginUser()
  {
    this._router.navigate(['./loginUser']);
    this.subscription= Observable.interval(500).subscribe(x => {
     this._communication.currentSubject.subscribe( resp => {
      if(resp===true){
          this.ngOnInit();
          this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    })
  });
```

}

trigger:

```
public onSubmit(){
          this._userService.signup(this.userAux, 'true').subscribe(
        resp2 => {
          this.token = resp2.token;
          if (this.token.length <= 0) {
            alert('El token no se ha generado');
          } else {
            localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
            this._communication.change(true);
            this._router.navigate(['./']);
          }
        },
        err => {
          const errorMessage = <any>err;
          if (errorMessage != null) {
            const body = JSON.parse(err._body);
            this.errorMessage = body.message;
          }
        }
}
```

The response is allways false, the flow of execution is first loginUser() keep listening every 0,5 sec subscribing to the Observable Object, then the component trigger calls change() after that Observable.interval keep listening but the value is false

Comment: where do you call onSubmit? if you do not call inside loginUser() it will never change the flag